# FriendlyChat - data nas mensagens

Tags: java, android, firebase

Implementei no meu projeto Android Studio o FriendlyChat disponibilizado no codelab.
Mas nas mensagens não tem data e hora.
Como Implementar a data e hora neste projeto?

[Neste link estão os códigos do Friendly Chat](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firebase-android/#0)

Alguém poderia me socorrer ?

Answer (score 2):

Primeiramente, você teria que editar a classe `FriendlyMessage` e colocar um atributo que suporte a informação de Data e Hora. A Classe `Calendar` ou `Date` são ótimas para isso. [Aqui](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) estão mais informações para a classe `Calendar`.
Faça os métodos de get e set, assim como tem para os outros atributos.

Em seguida, você terá que incluir no layout das mensagens, `item_message`, uma `TextView` para apresentar a data e hora. Você também terá que alterar o Adapter das mensagens para mostrar a informação corretamente.

Depois é só você alterar o método `populateViewHolder()` para definir a `TextView` da data com o método de capturar a data da `FriendlyMessage`.

Se de tudo não funcionar, veja como ele mostra as mensagens e o nome e tente copiar o método para data.